# Reproject by Estimate_utm_crs()

Tags: python, rasterio, utm, rioxarray

If I am using function `x.rio.reproject(x.rio.estimate_utm_crs())` then am I actually considering also parallels? The width and height of pixel changes with different longitude for me, however, The UTM doesn't consider parallels... I cannot find some proper references for this function.